# Unable to create Android AVD because of Target and CPU/ABI settings?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, eclipse-juno

I'm running Juno and just beginning to learn Android programming on **Mac**, on the latest SDK, 4.2 (API 17), and when I try to create an AVD, and as you can see from the screenshot (actually never mind, as a new user I'm not allowed to post a screen shot), I can input my Title, I can also choose my device, but when I try to change the dropdown menus of the target and CPU/ABI options, they don't drop at all. Also, the typical hardware box in which you add and delete chosen hardware, is not present, maybe just because of the newer Eclipse version. Anyhow, why aren't these options given to me? Also, this ends up in me having an "OK" button still being grayed out. Thanks!

Comment: You should try this [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbM78BIr25Q)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Firstly go to [SDK manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) plugin of Your eclipse/Android Studio and choose the API level for which you are going to create Android Virtual Device. And make sure that API's SDK Platform is installed. If SDK showing Not installed , then firstly download it.

After automatic Installation on Downloading completion. Restart your eclipse. Start your AVD plugin and then select the API for your AVD that you download.

Check this image, it showing that SDK platform for API 17 is installed. So we can create AVD of API 17. BUT we cant create AVD of API 16, because it is not installed yet.

[image]

Comment: Very helpful! I did what you said, but for some reason I had to restart the program twice to do the trick.

Comment: i mention that you need to restart eclipse after downloading. To make the download apply.

Comment: OSX: I installed everything with Android Studios' SDK Manager but I still see only one Target API (23) and no CPU/ABI's. Android Studios' AVD Manager shows everything I've downloaded, but can't get them into OS's android avd manager. Any hints? (Trying to use avd for NativeScript)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use SDK MANAGER to check if your .img files exist or not
2. try to check for eclipse updates
3. try to download another API like API 16 to see if it works or not