# Android: Emulator in Android Studio doesn't start/launch

Tags: android, android-studio

The problem is when I want to start the emulator nothing happens

Only this appears:

```
Waiting for device.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Test-AVD -netspeed full -netdelay no
```

Even if I create a complete new project it doesn't work.

I waited for 60 mins nothing happens. Thats why I'm asking.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it ?

best regards

Comment: May be this post will do for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717064/android-emulator-in-android-studio-doesnt-start?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Android Studio is waiting for you to start the virtual device.
You can do that from AVD Manager --> 'Select the device you chose in Android Studio' --> Start.
I hope this answers your question