# android studio - emulator doesn't work and genymotion doesn't get recognized

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, genymotion

I'm building an app in Android Studio (beta) 0.8.9, though I can't seem to get emulators running. I've made a Nexus 4 and 5 emulator through the options, but I can't seem to get them started. It shows this in the Run App tab.

```
Waiting for device.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd smallEmulator -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

So either it's not starting up, or I'm just an impatient SOB.

I've also downloaded Genymotion and started up an emulator through that, but now Android Studio doesn't recognize the emulator anymore. I try to run my app and check for any running devices, but it doesn't show up, despite the fact that it actually is running.

I've added the Genymotion plug-in, to no avail. No idea what went wrong.

I also have a One Plus One, which I'm not sure how I can debug on that. They don't seem to have drivers for that and haven't immediatly found anything on Google so far.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I fixed my problem. I used Genymotion to fix the problem. The running emulator wasn't turning up, because the android SDK's weren't linked to one another. Genymotion and Android Studio used different ones. So I edited Genymotion's settings to use the same one of AS and now it works!

Comment: I would try to start the emulator from command line, to see if it prints any additional errors. Also you can start emulator from Android AVD manager (you can find it in Android Studio menu, Tools / Android / AVD Manager), but I think it will work the same (won't work). I'm on Linux, so no much help from me.

Comment: You may want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717064/android-emulator-in-android-studio-doesnt-start?rq=1

Comment: No, neither of those solutions work for me :/ I'd already reduced the RAM to 700-ish MB and I'm fairly sure the Android versions are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, update android studio. Check if the emulators run from the AVD manager outside Android Studio, I mean by starting it up manually from ur SDK installation folder (AVD Manager.exe) . Check the path of ur emulator in **.ini** file in C:>Users>user-name >**.android**>avd. U can make a system variable for ur SDK folder "ANDROID_SDK_HOME" and place the .android folder's content there (the whole .android folder). Sometimes "resetting the adb" after u run emulator may work.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate explenation. I updated my Android Studio, had to move the sdk folder during that update. I tried to launch AVD manager.exe, but he says he can't find tools\android.bat: even though the file is there, one layer above the .exe. 
I'm going to try the system variable one right now.

Comment: I m sure system variable will work. ITs the way to tell where to look for ur sdk and .android (emulators config). See if it works n let me know .

Comment: Yeah, I got it working! I didn't end up using the system variable approach, but rather linking Genymotion and Android Studio's sdk's to one another.

Comment: how did u link, u mean u set the same sdk for both ? just to know..I think changing the location of the .android is better, bcos by default it resides in C drive and takes a lot of space..

Comment: well I updated Android Studio to the latest version and the update demanded that I relocate the sdk folder. So instead of in the C/Android/Android Studio folder, I moved it to my main user profile. 
I went into Genymotion's settings as well, network tab I think. There you have the choice to make Genymotion use it's own default sdk or specify one yourself.

Comment: I still dont know why changing sdk works (though I did it) bcos it should work with whatever the sdk is...but whatever.. it works now  :D

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier fix than what was previously mentioned. Try opening Android Studio, go to File, Settings, plugins.  Select the “Browse Repositories” button at the bottom of the page. Scroll down the displayed page to find “Genymotion”; select it and install it.

When it has installed, restart Android Studio.  Again, go to File, Settings, then go to Other Settings.  Genymotion should show up as an option.  There will be a field that asks for the path to the Genymotion folder.

Mine was: `C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion`.  At any rate, enter the path, click Apply or OK and Android Studio should recognize Genymotion  (You may need to restart AS once again).  Now you should have a small red icon on Android Studios tool bar; when you hover over it a pop up that identifies it as “Genymotion Device Manager”.  Click on it, select a device to load, click start and allow the virtual device to start completely.  Now run your Android Studio project; the Android Studio “Device Chooser” will pop up.  You should see the Genymotion device you’d started previously, select it and you’re good.

Hope this helps…