# Not able to launch emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am a newbie to Android just installed Android Studio and was trying to run an app ,but the emulator itself is not getting launched I have installed all the required packages has said in other posts,but its not working out for me.I have created a virtual device has well.

I am just getting

Waiting for device.
C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none

Comment: I am also waiting for the Answer

Comment: what is your system configuration?

Comment: Have you installed haxm?

Comment: You could try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16850152/4152581

Comment: You can try genymotion. It's much faster

Comment: @DavidPilkington 
I got this error after running from cmd                       :\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools>emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation
urrently requires hardware acceleration!
lease ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
PU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: but its installed i checked from sdk manager

Comment: @DavidPilkington i have tried to install from extras folder but i am getting computer does not support virtulization technology,what should be done in this case?

Comment: Chances are that your CPU/mobo is too old or doesnt have virtualisation enbaled

Comment: what is the other way round to get the emulator working if we dont have virtualization @DavidPilkington,@Amitabha Biswas,@Chinmay Sarupria,@Piotr Golinski

Comment: Try and have a look at GenyMotion

Comment: check this answer please http://stackoverflow.com/a/34282302/4919237

Answer (score 0):

Change the configuration to add more ram. Additionally you must note that the emulator is extremely slow at first startup. You have to give it a looot of time, but it will appear.