# FATAL:.//android/base/sockets/SocketWaiter.cpp:88:Check failed: isValidFd(fd). fd 1152 max1024 error in android

Tags: android, sockets, android-studio

I am facing problem in android app development. I'm getting this error **FATAL:.//android/base/sockets/SocketWaiter.cpp:88:Check failed: isValidFd(fd). fd 1152 max1024**

There are some solution available to it most of them are adding some command line parameter in emulator tab.
But in newer version of Android Studio there is no emulator tab under

```
Run-> EditConfigure-> app
```

[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjUTA.png)

So my question are

1. From where I can give these parameter to emulator in GUI.
2. Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: People who are down voting my question at least comment the reason of down voting If you have valid reasons.

Comment: follow this to remove this problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/16850152/2926806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving RAM of just 768 MB works on window and it resolve the problem.
Below is a link of stackoverflow from where I got a way to make it work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16850152/2926806