# Android Studio stuck at Virtual Device Configuration

Tags: android, android-studio

I got a new computer and downloaded Android Studio on it. It's a custom built Windows computer. When I try to create a virtual device or install a new API level, the window pops up to show the installation or the virtual device manager but it is only a white screen/box with the words Virtual Device Configuration in the corner.

I'm not sure what to do, has anyone had this problem before or have any idea as to how to fix it? Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717064/emulator-in-android-studio-doesnt-start

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the windows size by grabbing the side and dragging it. It sounds weird, but I had the same problem and changed the size of the window and for some odd reason it worked. I hope this helps.