# My Android Studio emulator keeps showing an error message

Tags: java, android-studio

emulator:

```
WARNING: could not load skin file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources/nexus_6/layout', using built-in one

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

The above is the error message that the emulator keeps showing. What do i do?

Comment: Try changing the emulator skin. Use a Nexus 5 or Nexus One instead

Comment: You try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30627815/1767021 or this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26355645/1767021

Answer (score 0):

To address the ERROR (not the warning):

You need to install the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM).  You can download it [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) or install it via your Android SDK Manager under `Extras`.
[image]