# Emulator stuck on loading screen in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

I decided to try Android Studio 2.0 having used Eclipse in the past, but I'm having considerable difficulty getting the Android virtual device (AVD) to load correctly. 
I've done quite a bit of googling and research into the problem. So far, nothing has worked.

The emulator simply hangs on the Android load-up screen every time I try to run it. I've seen it advised to use Genymotion, but I would prefer to first resolve the issue natively in Android Studio to feel confident going forward using the IDE for building projects.

The bullets below list what I've tried.
The majority of the suggestions I found are either from other similar Stack Overflow questions or from googling. 
None of them has resolved the problem.

- Complete reinstall of Android
- Complete reinstall of the software development kit (SDK), and of the SDK Tools
- Install and configure of Intel x86 accelerator
- Lowering the RAM to 512 in the AVD settings
- Multiple attempts at deleting and recreating AVDs
- Creating different AVD phone models (Nexus One, Nexus 5x, etc.)
- Resetting the Android debug bridge (ADB) in the AVD Monitor Tool
- Starting the ADB server from a terminal
- Restarting Android Studio multiple times after changes
- Several times running updates of the SDK, and the SDK Tools
- Made sure the SDK path is correct

When I run the emulator, it currently displays the following in the run window:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23
Warning: requested ram_size 1024M too big, reduced to 512M
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 228MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

The emulator shows up fine in the Android AVD Monitor devices pane and even appears to go through the entire booting process on the emulator screen itself, but never gets to the Android home screen.
Also, Logcat seems to be looping continuously through dozens of errors and warnings, which don't offer any clear indication of what the issue might be or any direction of how to resolve it.

I feel like I've exhausted every idea and am not sure how to move forward. Just for the record, I am running El Capitan 10.9.2 with a 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo and 4 GB RAM. It's not the fastest machine, for sure, but should be capable of running Android Studio and the emulator.

Comment: This happened to me just about *every* time I reloaded a project. – It turned out there were bugs in the code. For example, one variable was given different names in different components, although it really was the very same variable.
So checking the code for serious bugs might be a good idea – in addition to the extremely time-consuming solution suggested in the highest-voted answer.

Answer (score 89):

For me this worked: in AVD(Tools->AVD) click on the small arrow for desired emulator then click on "Wipe data".

After that, it successfully started - passed the android logo screen - although a bit slowly.

Comment: Confirmed. As I understand, this *maybe* happen, when you download a newer android image in the same virtual device, where data from previous android image exists.

Comment: It looks odd but wiping data right after creatioin helped to run hi-res 1440x2560 AVD, no freezes. Other AVDs with more low-res ran with no issues, but hi-res was stucking... Tnx!

Comment: Worked for me, I know I started the AVD first time by accident and I didn't let it finish as I was using a real phone at the time.  So data was probably corrupt.  Thanks!

Comment: I didnt want to Wipe Data. I don't understand why there is no option to Restart a stuck emulator. It always Saves state when closed.

Answer (score 46):

You have two thing:

1. You should Increase your ADB emulator Heap to the minimum required.

   in your case: 512M

   into your AVD Manager:

   > - Click Edit on your Emulator
   > - "Show Advanced Settings" at the bottom
   > - Go to: "Memory and Storage"
   > - Edit the VM heap value to 512 MB
   > - Finished

   Image:

   [image: EDIT AVD]

   [image: Show advanced settings]

   [image: Edit VM heap]
2. You can Wipe data to your Emulator. [here is an exemple website](https://fluttermaster.com/clear-data-on-android-virtual-device/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Sadly didn't work for me.Emulator still just hangs on Android boot screen.

Comment: On my Mac, the default for my tablet was 96 MB. I changed this to 512 and it worked for me.

Comment: @mikeym reduce the ram to 512

Comment: On mine, both RAM and VM Heap are non-editable. Any idea why?

Comment: @JustinLloyd, your device is enabled? Try to turn off befoee

Comment: The answer posted by @arcol is the right answer. Your approach doesn't work.

Comment: I had to increase my `VM Heap` to **1024**

Answer (score 12):

At one point my laptop hit a kernel panic and restarted while running an active AVD emulator session. When attempting to restart the emulator, the emulated device (Pixel 3) stayed stuck on the startup splash logo screen.

Fix steps:

1. Stop hung emulator session.
2. `rm ~/.android/avd/name_of_emulated_device.avd/*.lock`
3. `rm ~/.android/avd/name_of_emulated_device.avd/*.qcow2`
4. Restarting the emulated AVD should now be successful.

Windows equivalent for `~/.android` should be `C:\Users\.android`, but I can't confirm this myself.

Note: You will likely lose any additionally installed apps and current work that was on the AVD.

Comment: My AVD device was always stuck at launch time, leading to the app installation process to loop until timeout, and this solution worked well for me, thanks!

Comment: This essentially wipes all user data.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, increasing the heap size didn't help in my case. The virtual device was actually running fine before with the previous amount of heap.

What I eventually ended up doing was just creating a new virtual device through the AVD manager leaving most of the fields the default value. The new device ran fine and booted up as expected and was able to run my app. It's possible something in my first virtual device became corrupted.

[image: Create Virtual Device]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm running El Capitan 10.11.5 with a 2.0GHz Intel Core 2 Duo and 8GB RAM, Android Studio 1.5.1.

After upgrading to Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer), rev 6.1.1 and deleting my API 14 SDK and related files, the newly installed API 23's Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image would not get past the Android logo screen.

After much trial & error, the Intel x86 Atom System Image (not Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image) for API 15 finally loaded the home screen on the emulator after ~ 8 min and one android system crash.

Will try the Intel x86 Atom System Image for API 23 later. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of the steps listed here helped me, either.

But since the solution that worked for me was not mentioned here yet, I thought it might help you or one of the others finding this thread:

What did work for me was disabling certain settings in my Avast Antivirus as proposed by the Android studio troubleshooting page [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-troubleshooting).

My version of Avast did not have the setting "Use nested virtualization when available", however just turning off "Enable Hardware assisted virtualization" (note: restart is required for it to take effect) solved the problem just fine.

So if you are using Avast or another Antivirus which manipulates virtualization, be sure to look through the correspondent settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced same problem, What I did was, I clicked on the drop down in the actions column, then clicked on wipe Data, and that resolved it for me on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30047842)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and running as admin fixed this (drove me crazy).
Hope this works for you too tried some many fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the advices. The only thing that worked for me was:

Change emulator settings

```
Emulated Performance - Graphics

from: Automatic 
to: Software (GLES 2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with my AVD. After lots of trial and error I arrived at a solution for my problem. the problem was with the Heap size and the RAM size.
Initially the default heap size was 128 MB and RAM was 1563 , I just changed the heap size to 512 MB and reduced the RAM size( high RAM was making my pc run slow) also I enabled hardware acceleration. And Yipeee, it worked.

Comment: This was already suggested over a year ago and didn't work. Please read others answers first before posting.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me?

- Create new project with same configs.
- And start your old emulators in it.

What did not work?

- Wiping data.
- Increasing Heap size.
- Creating new virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue and took more than a week to resolve this. Opening the app stuck in the splash screen itself. Now, it is fixed successfully.

steps to follow to fix the issue.
open AVD manager and click 3 dots

1. set RAM  - 1 GB
2. Heap - 512 MB
3. Graphics - Software GLES 2.0
4. Wipe data.

These will fix the issue. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding a system image for a new Virtual Device, this way even the old emulated device worked again:

> Tools> Device Manager> Click on the + sign(top-left)> pick up a device from the list> download the new system image> follow the proposed steps.

Answer (score -2):

It's very easy to fix all you need to do is go in AVD Manager click on the small arrow on most right side of the screen beside the edit icon. Click that small arrow and select wipe data.
Now when you'll start your AVD it will restart and work properly.