# Why don't all of the ADV devices work except Pixel XL device in android studio emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, flutter

I'm new in flutter framework, and of course, in android programming. What I've tried to ran some devices use ADV in the android studio but unfortunately when I run most of them are stuck except Pixel XL device. I don't know why Pixel XL worked but for example Pixel 2 XL doesn't work of course it isn't just about Pixel 2 XL I have a the same problem with nexus 6.and I also check this questions but it didn't work for me.

[AVD Emulator stuck on loading screen in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753354/avd-emulator-stuck-on-loading-screen-in-android-studio)

```
my Laptop specification: OS : Windows 10 x64 / SSD : 512GB / HDD : 1TB 
CPU : Core i7-7700HQ 2.80 / Memory : 24GB / Graphic: Geforece GTX 1050
```

---

[image]

> Name: Pixel_2_XL_API_28
>
> CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64)
>
> Path: C:\Users\Behnam.android\avd\Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd
>
> Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 28)
>
> Skin: pixel_2_xl
>
> SD Card: 512 MB
>
> fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile:
>
> runtime.network.speed: full
>
> hw.accelerometer: yes
>
> hw.device.name: pixel_2_xl
>
> hw.lcd.width: 1440
>
> hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
>
> image.androidVersion.api: 28
>
> tag.id: google_apis
>
> hw.mainKeys: no
>
> hw.camera.front: emulated
>
> avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 2 XL API 28
>
> hw.gpu.mode: host
>
> hw.ramSize: 1536
>
> PlayStore.enabled: false
>
> fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
>
> hw.cpu.ncore: 4
>
> hw.keyboard: yes
>
> hw.sensors.proximity: yes
>
> hw.dPad: no
>
> hw.lcd.height: 2880
>
> vm.heapSize: 384
>
> skin.dynamic: yes
>
> hw.device.manufacturer: Google
>
> hw.gps: yes
>
> hw.audioInput: yes
>
> image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-28\google_apis\x86_64\
>
> showDeviceFrame: yes
>
> hw.camera.back: virtualscene
>
> AvdId: Pixel_2_XL_API_28
>
> hw.lcd.density: 560
>
> hw.arc: false
>
> hw.device.hash2: MD5:1a4fa6b2569f0b76bfb9824b6b6fc976
>
> fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
>
> fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
>
> hw.trackBall: no
>
> hw.battery: yes
>
> hw.sdCard: yes
>
> tag.display: Google APIs
>
> runtime.network.latency: none
>
> disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
>
> hw.sensors.orientation: yes
>
> avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
>
> hw.gpu.enabled: yes

---

> Name: Pixel_XL_API_28
>
> CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64)
>
> Path: C:\Users\Behnam.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_28.avd
>
> Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 28)
>
> Skin: pixel_xl_silver
>
> SD Card: 512M
>
> fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile:
>
> runtime.network.speed: full
>
> hw.accelerometer: yes
>
> hw.device.name: pixel_xl
>
> hw.lcd.width: 1440
>
> hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
>
> image.androidVersion.api: 28
>
> tag.id: google_apis
>
> hw.mainKeys: no
>
> hw.camera.front: emulated
>
> avd.ini.displayname: Pixel XL API 28
>
> hw.gpu.mode: auto
>
> hw.ramSize: 1536
>
> PlayStore.enabled: false
>
> fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
>
> hw.cpu.ncore: 4
>
> hw.keyboard: yes
>
> hw.sensors.proximity: yes
>
> hw.dPad: no
>
> hw.lcd.height: 2560
>
> vm.heapSize: 384
>
> skin.dynamic: yes
>
> hw.device.manufacturer: Google
>
> hw.gps: yes
>
> hw.audioInput: yes
>
> image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-28\google_apis\x86_64\
>
> showDeviceFrame: yes
>
> hw.camera.back: virtualscene
>
> AvdId: Pixel_XL_API_28
>
> hw.lcd.density: 560
>
> hw.arc: false
>
> hw.device.hash2: MD5:984dbf66b1aaafcdb7e89573ffb74b46
>
> fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
>
> fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
>
> hw.trackBall: no
>
> hw.battery: yes
>
> hw.sdCard: yes
>
> tag.display: Google APIs
>
> runtime.network.latency: none
>
> disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
>
> hw.sensors.orientation: yes
>
> avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
>
> hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out what was my issue. It comes from Graphics card drivers I downgrade graphics card driver to the lower version (latest version to 376.54) everything is well right now. My graphics card is Geforece GTX 1050