# my application is not showing up in the emulator (tried all the solutions on stackoverflow)

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion, android-launcher

I am a complete beginner in Android and as the title says my application is not showing up in the emulator (tried all the solutions on stackoverflow)

troubleshooting that i did:

1)used genymotion

2)made sure that I have `

```
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>`
```

3)unchecked the ABD integration

4)the same version for the SDK

5)installed HAXM at a previous point and made sure from the BIOS that the visualization is enabled

My complete Mainfest after many editing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lenovo.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you get any message ?

Comment: @JohnJoe no errors at all " emulator: device fd:1208
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554"

Comment: Have you installed HAXM ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30627815/5156075

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes installed it at a previous point and made sure from the BIOS that the visualization is enabled

Comment: Try to check in real device for better understading.

Comment: Uncheck `Enable ADB Integration` from `Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration`.

Comment: @Harisali already unchecked

Comment: @ERVishalSenjaliya it's not always available as I am an iOS user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build the apk independently then drag and drop it into the genymotion  emulator.

Comment: Thanks. didn't notice that before and it works finalllyyy