# Android Emulator is not running on Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

I am trying to create a demo instant app which was demonstrated at Google IO 2017. I see, this needs Android Studio 3.0 and latest build tools and only few devices are white-listed to use this newly introduced concept.

Here, you can see that I have created an avd machine named `Nexus 5X`, I captured details of created machine, here you can see:

```
Name: Nexus_5X_API_25
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Path: C:\Users\williams\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_25.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 25)
Skin: nexus_5x
SD Card: C:\Users\williams\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_25.avd\sdcard.img
hw.dPad: no
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: Nexus 5X
vm.heapSize: 256
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 25
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-25\google_apis\x86\
tag.id: google_apis
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: emulated
hw.mainKeys: no
AvdId: Nexus_5X_API_25
hw.camera.front: emulated
hw.lcd.density: 420
avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5X API 25
hw.gpu.mode: guest
hw.device.hash2: MD5:1be89bc42ec9644d4b77968b23474980
hw.ramSize: 1536
hw.trackBall: no
PlayStore.enabled: false
hw.battery: yes
hw.cpu.ncore: 2
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Here is SDK tools snapshot:

[image]

Well, I am facing some challenges when I am running this emulator. It does not do anything when I click on run button of this emulator.

Here are the error logs:

```
Emulator: Could not launch 'C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory

Emulator: [12360]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 2
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with this configuration ? BTW I have checked these [Emulator in Android Studio doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717064/emulator-in-android-studio-doesnt-start) but no luck.

Comment: May be you should try this https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: @Stallion Those devices are not white listed for Instant apps. I tried before creating avd machine. I was getting a warning message "Device is not whitelisted to run instant apps" kinda

Comment: `Android Emulator... Not installed`... Hmm I wonder if that could be the problem

Comment: Android Emulator 25.3.1 this works for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are certain multiple reasons for this issue, nevertheless you can give a try. Check if you have Android Emulator installed on your machine.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Z0i.png]

Comment: Where can I find this window that you presented here?

Comment: @DJGruby Android Studio > SDK Manager

Comment: The "Android Emulator" is checked but still starting the emulator throws same error

Answer (score 2):

Simple I did following steps and achieve task in MAC Machine, You can do in windows machine too

1) Go to Android Studio > SDK Manager 
2) Select SDK Tools Tab 
3) Select SHOW PACKAGE DETAILS Check box at bottom 
4) Search for ANDROID EMULATOR Then 
   i) If already selected then unchecked and press Apply button 
   ii) If already not selected then checked and press Apply button 
   iii) Done Above (i) then select once for install the Android Emulator.

That's It!

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio AVD Manager will allow you to create an AVD, however your log error message and SDK Manager screenshot indicate you do not actually have the Android Emulator installed.

To develop with Instant Apps on the emulator, you need two things:

1. Android Emulator v26.1+ (you may need to change your Android Studio update channel to canary)
   [image: Android Emulator]
2. Use the Android O - "Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image" for your AVD. Android O has a a couple built-in platform features for Instant Apps that you will want to test. You need the Google Play store version, because the Instant Apps are distributed via Google Play Services and the Google Play store. For additional validation there is a Google Play enable system image for Android Nougat (API 24). 
   [image: Google Play emulator system image]

Comment: Where do you find the AVD manager? It's not in tools drop down: https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/3G3b0r2d0G253R1t3h2Q/Screen%20Shot%202017-11-01%20at%2019.32.02.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=220295

Comment: To find the AVD Manager, check out the top of this site: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 1):

Install Android Auto Desktop Head Unit emulator .
and then restart the emulator from avd manager

Its worked for me.

Comment: this is mysterious, but i'll try it