# Android Studio (3.0) Emulator Not Working After The Latest Update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Emulator is not starting. I just updated the Android Studio nothing was done other than that.

The below notifications show up and nothing happens when I run the Emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, try setting the OpenGL ES version to automatic in the emulator by going to "Emulated Performance" under the emulator settings:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiLd7.png]

Alternatively, it could be a problem with a file in the SDK. From what I can find, this is mostly a problem with the linux based operating systems. There is a specific file you need, that you may need to manually install (which you probably need). So first off, installing it:

If you have a 32 bit system:

```
# apt-get install lib64stdc++6
```

Or a 64 bit system with multiarch enabled:

```
# apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386
```

And then, move the file:

```
$ cd $ANDROID_HOME/sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 $ANDROID_HOME/sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

Note that the actual path you use could be different depending on `$ANDROID_HOME`. And make sure you set `ANDROID_HOME` to the location of the SDK before you do this, otherwise you have to type the full path to the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

### Symptom:

Emulator not launching or starting.

### Errors:

> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
>   Or
>   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
>   Or
>   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 2

---

### Cause (in Linux):

> As Google seems to be not aware of the problem, on every update they make to the Android Emulator package in Android Studio, they break the funcionality replacing your working SDK C++ libs with the broken/older ones.

### Solution:

> Create a simlink to the lib distributed with Ubuntu:
>
> ```
> cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/
>
> mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
>
> mv libstdc++.so.6.0.18 libstdc++.so.6.0.18.bak
>
> ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6
>
> ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
> ```

---

### Cause (in Windows):

Android Emulator not installed:
[image]

### Solution:

> Install *Android Emulator* if it's not installed on **SDK Manager** > **SDK Tools**:
>
> [image]

---

### References:

1) [Android Emulator is not running on Android Studio 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128018/android-emulator-is-not-running-on-android-studio-3-0)

2) [Emulator on Android Studio doesn't start after SDK tools update to 25.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659272/emulator-on-android-studio-doesnt-start-after-sdk-tools-update-to-25-3-1)

3) [Cannot launch emulator on Linux (Ubuntu 15.10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911302/cannot-launch-emulator-on-linux-ubuntu-15-10)

4) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37075150

Comment: True, but if you notice the OpenGL ES errors you'll know this is something else. If it doesn't boot it doesn't show a bunch of OpenGL ES errors (I had the problem where the emulator doesn't boot myself). OP asks a question about what appears to be an emulator crash, not it not booting

Comment: @Zoe OP: Emulator is not starting.

Comment: Wrong. The emulator is starting, but crashing. True, that means it isn't starting, but the linked question is for when it doesn't have **any kind of response**. As in pressing the launch button and nothing happens. The emulator crashes, meaning the emulator component of the SDK has to be present for it to happen

Comment: Yes that's true

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wiping the data before launch?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings**/**Advanced**/**OpenGL ES renderer**

and enabling **SwiftShader** instead Autodetect worked for me.

[image: Enabled SwiftShader]

Answer (score -2):

you should install android emulator because it become Separated API 
n SDK Manager > SDK Tools: and install it