# Why is the Android Studio emulator giving me a framebuffer error on startup?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm on a Windows 7 PC. When I run the Android emulator from Android Studio on the command line, I get this error:

```
Failed on eglChooseConfig
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

I can fix it by selecting software rendering, but that's really slow, and the GPU emulation was working a couple days before; it just suddenly stopped working.

I've tried changing it not to use multi-core CPU since it's labelled experimental, but I get the same problem.

Update: I just upgraded from AS 2.3.3 to 3.0.1. It installed a bunch of new emulator software, and I still get the same error.

Settings shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working because the display was set to 16-bit color. Set it to 32-bit color, and this particular issue may go away; there are other possible things that can cause the error.

[image]