# Could not start AVD Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I wanted to start coding an app in Android Studio. I coded a bit but when I want to start my application "Could not start AVD" pops up. I have installed 2 virtual devices, none of these devices works. So I thought it was a problem with my code. I created a new project, just with the text "Hello World" and "Could not start AVD" pops up again.

I wachted tutorials on YouTube and this never happened to others. I dont think I make something wrong. I cant explain myself, why this doesnt work. Can anyone help me? Do you need any further information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emulator in Android Studio doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717064/emulator-in-android-studio-doesnt-start)