# How to decrease the start time of the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to run the Android Emulator from Android Studio, but the emulator doesn't load, it takes a long time but it doesn't load, I've already tried several hardware configurations but it doesn't work and everyone got 99% CPU usage.

I've already tried

- Windows 10 Pro 1909 x64 / OS Build 18363.1256
- Intel Duo Core E8400 3.00Ghz Family 6 Model 7
- 8 GB memory
- Video Card GeForce 980 GT
- Android Studio 4.1.1
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86)

Is there a tip to reduce the weight of the Emulator and load faster? Is there a lighter version of the AVD?

Thanks

Comment: Tried [any of these?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717064/emulator-in-android-studio-doesnt-start)

Comment: You should specify the CPU make/model, system OS (Win/Linux/Mac) and version, along with what version of HAXM you are running.

Comment: ok, I am sorry, Question Edited

Comment: You need install HAXM (Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator)