# Android Studio AVD Emulator doesn't start

Tags: android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have an emulator in Android Studio, which was created with the AVD Manager.
It has 2048mb of RAM
The API is the last, 30.
But when I try to compile my app the emulator doesn't start.
I have a message that says

```
No emulators are currently running.
To launch an emulator, use the AVD Manager or run your app while targeting
a virtual device.
```

I've tried to delete the emulator and create a new emulator but it doesn't run.
I have no messages in Logcat.

Edit: When I try to run the emulator from AVD Manager window, I have a message where says "The emulator process for AVD mycompanynameemulator_API_30 has terminated.

Comment: You shall follow this [official documentation from Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app#Emulator) on how start emulator and run app accordingly

Comment: Thanks. I am using that method but the emulator doesn't start when I press play. Before having this issue, the emulator was opening in a window with the title qemu-system but now that window doesn't open.

Comment: You can try [troubleshooting via this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717064/emulator-in-android-studio-doesnt-start) as here we would need more context but its better if you go through thoroughly first on you machine

Answer (score 0):

When I had 4 GB ram, I used to get the same messages whenever I tried to start emulator. Then I increased my ram to 12 GB and the emulator started working. Increase your ram to more than 8 GB and the problem will be solved.

Comment: I have increased the amount of ram to 12GB but the problem persists