# Android Emulator error: Couldn't configure security system

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, qemu

Full log:

```
avd@avd:~$ DISPLAY=:1 Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd avd1_oreo
INFO    | Android emulator version 33.1.23.0 (build_id 11150993) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/avd/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-27/google_apis/arm64-v8a/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 16123
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file /home/avd/.android/avd/../avd/avd1_oreo.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
WARNING | Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering.
library_mode swangle_indirect gpu mode swangle_indirect
I1208 15:12:09.126044   16123 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
I1208 15:12:09.143677   16123 FrameBuffer.cpp:486] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (Google Inc.)
I1208 15:12:09.144018   16123 FrameBuffer.cpp:487] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Google SwiftShader)
I1208 15:12:09.144169   16123 FrameBuffer.cpp:488] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 SwiftShader 4.0.0.1)
I1208 15:12:09.144334   16123 FrameBuffer.cpp:489] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 
I1208 15:12:09.144517   16123 FrameBuffer.cpp:490] Graphics Device Extensions N/A
WARNING: cannnot unmap ptr 0x7fcf31aed000 as it is in the protected range from 0x7fcf31aed000 to 0x7fcfb1ced000
WARNING: cannnot unmap ptr 0x7fcfb1c01000 as it is in the protected range from 0x7fcf31aed000 to 0x7fcfb1ced000
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/0) is not owned by us (uid 1001), but by uid 0! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
pulseaudio: pa_context_connect() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Connection refused
pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextCould not init `pa' audio driver
WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
ERROR   | Couldn't configure security system.
WARNING | Overwriting existing discovery file: /run/user/0/avd/running/pid_16123.ini
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/0/avd/running/pid_16123.ini
qemu-system-aarch64: PCI bus not available for hda
WARNING | QEMU main loop exits abnormally with code 1
INFO    | Wait for emulator (pid 16123) 10 seconds to shutdown gracefully before kill;you can set environment variable ANDROID_EMULATOR_WAIT_TIME_BEFORE_KILL(in seconds) to change the default value (20 seconds)
Killed
```

I have no idea what this "security system" is and if this is the actual cause of the crash. Is it related to SELinux possibly?

Comment: I had very similar problem. Check my case and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77818145/3160049).

Answer (score 0):

I searched the source code and found out this message is printed due to a gRPC failure, as the previous warning suggests.