# How to create AVD in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have a problem in creating a new android virtual device in eclipse (Eclipse Java EE).

the first problem is i cannot find the "AVD manager" button when i click in "Window" in eclipse.

[image: "Window"]

i tried to access to the AVD manager by opening `monitor.bat` in `tools folder`
and the second problem was that when i fill the AVD window i see that `OK` Button is unavailable.

[image: Screenshot show the AVD manager button]

thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would advise uninstalling eclipse and installing Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html do it now before you get any further! (eclipse support is officially withdrawn and AndroidStudio is the recommended IDE for Android development)

Comment: (change the Target to one where "you have a system image installed" and the OK button will be available)

Comment: Android 4.4.2 is already installed, the OK button still unavailable

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000200/unable-to-create-android-avd-because-of-target-and-cpu-abi-settings/14000661#14000661

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open "SDK Manager" and install an emulator image ("Android 4.4 Intel Atom x86 System Image" or something like that). "CPU/ABI" is a required field when you're creating a new emulator. You haven't chosen one (and probably you haven't installed one) - that's why OK button is disabled.

[image: SDK Manager]

Comment: Problem Solved!